# How can I set the host property which includes a namespace, as well as have a set namespace

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

So I have:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({

    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
      namespace: 'index.php?r=api',
      host: "http://localhost/foo"

  })
});
```

Except when a request is made, the `foo` part of the url is ignored and the requested url looks like `http://localhost/index.php?r=api/model` instead of `http://localhost/foo/index.php?r=api/model`. Is this a bug or am I not using this correctly?

I know I can add the `foo` to the namespace and it will work. However, my coworkers have several different Apache configurations and structures (I know that it isn't ideal, but I have not had time to finalize a standard vagrant setup). So their code might be under `localhost/foo` or `localhost/bar` or just `localhost`.

Comment: see my comment to your answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Ember.js, but I know that with URLs if you make `index.php?r=api` relative to the base `http://localhost/foo`, it replaces `foo` with `index.php?r=api`.

Therefore, adding a forward-slash at the end of the base URL (e.g. `/foo/`) should cause the `index.php?r=api` part to be *appended*, rather than replacing `foo`.

The following code has a forward-slash added:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({

    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
      namespace: 'index.php?r=api',
      host: "http://localhost/foo/"

  })
});
```

Comment: If I add the trailing forward slash, it comes out http://localhost/foo//index.php?r=api

Comment: @CullyMason Is that actually a problem? I'm not sure about Apache, but IIS doesn't mind about double forward-slashes.